# Stop function is not working as expected. Need Help. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm new to React and I have made a timer that increases after clicking on Start. Similarly, I made a stop button to stop the timer and set the variable to 0. But what's happening is it starts again from 0.

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

```
import React from 'react';
class Timer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
            secondsElapsed: 0
        };
    }
    start = () => {
        this.setState({
            secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1
        });
    }
    stop = () => {
        this.setState({
            secondsElapsed: 0
        });
    }

    handleClick = (e) => {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.start, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return ( <React.Fragment><br/>
        <ul>
                    <li><span onClick = {this.handleClick}> Start Timer <br/><br/></span></li>
                    <li><span onClick = {this.stop}> Stop Timer </span></li>
        </ul>
                    
                    <Resultant new = {this.state.secondsElapsed}/> 
                </React.Fragment>);
            }
}
class Resultant extends React.Component {
    render() {
            return ( <div>
                        <h3> Seconds Elapsed: {this.props.new} </h3> 
                    </div>);
                }
}
export default Timer;
```

Comment: Check out my answer :) it should help you out and also describe a little more why is it hapenning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to clear the interval to stop the function from running repeatedly:

```
stop = () => {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.setState({
            secondsElapsed: 0
        });
    }
```

For more details about timing events in JavaScript [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Answer (score 3):

In your `stop()`, you are only resetting the `secondElapsed` state back to `0`. You also need to stop the interval from updating the state again.

You can try adding `clearInterval(this.interval)` in the `stop()`.

Comment: doesn't my answer covered yours?

Answer (score 3):

Change your stop function to this:

```
stop = () => {
    this.setState({
        secondsElapsed: 0
    });
    clearInterval(this.interval); // You should clear the interval to stop it from incrementing seconds when "stop" is pressed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

You are using [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) by assigning it to a value named `interval` by `this.interval = setInterval()` so it starts doing that each second but later after stopping it still uses it because you didn't stop interval so it is making it in the "background".

## Solution

You just need to add line with clearing interval in the beginning of your `stop` function like:

```
  stop = () => {
       clearInterval(this.interval)
       // rest of code
   }
```

so it will stop running that in the background even if you click on the stop button.